# Pdf videos on mobile phone

Tags: video, pdf

I put a video in my pdf with Acrobat and there I can watch my video. But if I open the pdf on my mobile, I can't watch the video, I only see an image. Is there a way to watch videos of a pdf in a mobile? I have a samsung J5.

Comment: Do you want to play the videos inside the pdf app like Acrobat or to play them using other apps.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio inside the pdf app on my mobile

Comment: Have you already tried [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.contentplayer)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio it says: "Flash is not supported"

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This time it crashed with another file

Comment: @Curio Sorry to hear that. Will keep searching a better one.

Comment: Again, which pdf app are you using to open videos

Comment: @beeshyams I tried with drive pdf viewer, ezPDF player and acrobat on my mobile

Comment: [This may help](https://www.wondershare.com/convert-video-audio/flash-player-for-samsung-galaxy.html)- can't verify since it seems to be Samsung issue and I don't have Samsung device

Comment: @beeshyams it doesn't work

Comment: [this may be the reason](http://samsung-galaxy-video-converter.blogspot.in/2016/06/best-video-format-for-galaxy-j3-j5-j7.html)

Comment: @beeshyams mmm and now? What can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71175/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-curio).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Wow, it works, I had to upload a smaller video. However it's quite ugly and there are some bugs

Comment: @Curio Yes the app has bugs, and sometimes when the video plays there are no images only the sound